# How do I write a script to call a REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to write a script which calls a REST API using a URL like:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/xyz
```

If I open this URL in the browser, it asks for a user email and password. Once I've authenticated, it returns a JSON response with a user id. I don't know how I should I authenticate through the script. Can someone give me a suggestion?

This is what I started with:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

api_url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1//user/xyz"

response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(api_url))
data = JSON.parse(response.body)
fields = data.keys
puts fileds
puts data.keys
```

This is the authentication for the API:

```
 before_filter :authorize, :except => [:keys]
private

      def authorize
        authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
          user = User.find_by_email(username)

          if user && user.valid_password?(password)
            sign_in :user, user
          end
        end
      end
```

How I can pass email and password to authenticate this API so I can get "id" as return?

Comment: That entirely depends on exactly how the API requires authentication. A `REST` api only provides conventions about data is retrieved, but it does _not_ let you assume anything about how authentication works. Is it HTTP auth? Or does it require a API token of some sort? Or are you presented with a form on a webpage asking you to login first? Or something else? Consult the documentation of the API to figure out how it wants credentials.

Comment: I have updated my code above to show authentication this api using.

Comment: Also consider using ActiveResource.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Basic authentication is pretty simple to add to your request, though I don't think you can use the `get_response` convenience method.

See: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-Basic+Authentication

Example from the documentation:

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html?key=value')

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass' # username, password go here.

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

Comment: `.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1860:in `initialize': undefined method `empty?' for #<URI::HTTP:0x007fe6f8975770> (NoMethodError)
 from /Users/nit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2093:in `initialize'
 from recdns_rest_get_arid.rb:6:in `new'
 from recdns_rest_get_arid.rb:6:in `<main>'` This is the error i am getting

Comment: Is there a way I can pass username and password when there is api call . And the username/passowrd I fill in popup will authenticate api and return expected result?

Comment: this what i am using now but authentication denied `require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

uri = URI('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/authkey')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'
    res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|

    http.request(req)
    }
puts res.body`

Answer (score 1):

[rest_client gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client) works great for me.  As far as what the API returns that should be in the documentation.  You can always try it in IRB and see what the response contains.